# Find Nearest Match from Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm creating a "simulation program" where I save positions of around 700 moving objects in a MongoDB. I'm saving all the positions in a collection and every document is one "Moving Object". As far as good.

Now my problem:
I would like to read ALL the positons from the 700 "Objects" with one query but the timestamps of the positions are variable...

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59522479707c4fbf16b2f91b"),
    "PuckId" : 0,
    "Positions" : [ 
        {
            "time" : 0,
            "x_pos" : 0,
            "y_pos" : 0,
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "time" : 10,
            "x_pos" : 5,
            "y_pos" : 5,
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "time" : 20,
            "x_pos" : 0,
            "y_pos" : 20,
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "time" : 25,
            "x_pos" : 5,
            "y_pos" : 10,
            "state" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59522660707c4fbf16b38701"),
    "PuckId" : 1,
    "Positions" : [ 
        {
            "time" : 1,
            "x_pos" : 1,
            "y_pos" : 0,
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "time" : 5,
            "x_pos" : 5,
            "y_pos" : 10,
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "time" : 8,
            "x_pos" : 0,
            "y_pos" : 2,
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "time" : 22,
            "x_pos" : 5,
            "y_pos" : 0,
            "state" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's what i've got so far:
(For this Example I'm trying to query the positons of the Object at Timesamp 10)

```
db.getCollection('LogFileV2').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Positions:{
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Positions",      //{$slice: ["$Positions",1]}, *see below
                    as: "pos",

                    cond: { 
                        $or: [{
                            $lt: ["$$pos.time", 10+1] //at Timestamp 10
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

- If I use `$slice' at this position it returns only the FIRST position. But I need only the latest position which depends on the timestamp (here 10) which I enter.

So what do I have to change to get this result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59522479707c4fbf16b2f91b"),
    "Positions" : [ 
        {
            "time" : 10,
            "x_pos" : 5,
            "y_pos" : 5,
            "state" : 1
        }
    ]
}
/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59522660707c4fbf16b38701"),
    "Positions" : [ 
        {
            "time" : 8,
            "x_pos" : 0,
            "y_pos" : 2,
            "state" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've added another document. Now you probably see that the timestamps aren't the same and I can't match and search for like 10 and that's it. If a document doesn't have time 10 then it should return the nearest other array entry.

Comment: Yes beacuse I have to know the exact position at a given time of all objects. And there's no option to "gues" the right timestamp to get the result.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I actually had not finished, and there is a faster variant as long as your MongoDB supports it.

Comment: Yes it does. Next week I will see if it's fast enough but for now it definitly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the nearest I would use something like this:

```
db.getCollection('LogFileV2').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Positions.time": { "$lte": 10 } } },
  { "$project": {
    "Positions": {
      "$map": {
        "input": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$Positions",
            "as": "pos",
            "cond": { "$lte": [ "$$pos.time", 10 ]  }
          }
        },
        "as": "pos",
        "in": {
          "time": "$$pos.time",
          "x_pos": "$$pos.x_pos",
          "y_pos": "$$pos.y_pos",
          "state": "$$pos.state",
          "diff": { "$subtract": [ 10, "$$pos.time" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Positions" },
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "Positions.diff": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "Positions": { "$first": "$Positions" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```

Which gives you:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59522479707c4fbf16b2f91b"),
    "Positions" : {
        "time" : 10.0,
        "x_pos" : 5.0,
        "y_pos" : 5.0,
        "state" : 1.0,
        "diff" : 0.0
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59522660707c4fbf16b38701"),
    "Positions" : {
        "time" : 8.0,
        "x_pos" : 0.0,
        "y_pos" : 2.0,
        "state" : 1.0,
        "diff" : 2.0
    }
}
```

So the basic alteration there apart from the query to eliminate the documents that do not meet the condition is the use of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to get the "difference" from the queried value.

Then we basically want to [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) the array results and only take the one that had the least difference. This you get via [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) with a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage.

Alternately you could define the array within [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) again against the [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) value. This would be faster where supported:

```
db.getCollection('LogFileV2').aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Positions.time": { "$lte": 10 } } },
  { "$project": {
    "Positions": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "filtered": {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$Positions",
                  "as": "pos",
                  "cond": { "$lte": [ "$$pos.time", 10 ]  }
                }
              },
              "as": "pos",
              "in": {
                "time": "$$pos.time",
                "x_pos": "$$pos.x_pos",
                "y_pos": "$$pos.y_pos",
                "state": "$$pos.state",
                "diff": { "$subtract": [ 10, "$$pos.time" ] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            { "$filter": {
              "input": "$$filtered",
              "as": "f",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$f.diff", { "$min": "$$filtered.diff" } ] }
            }},
            0
          ]
        }   
      }
    }
  }}
])
```